# Minimising ArangoDB memory use

Tags: arangodb

I have a number of different deployment situations for ArangoDB. One of which is on a users desktop machine or laptop.

I've read and implemented the instructions on how to run ArangoDB in Spartan Mode (very helpfull).

However, I need more. The desktop user may work with a number of different collections in the database and all of these stay loaded and consume a lot of virtual memory. This can cause some apps to behave differently if they detect they are running in a memory constrained environment.

So, I'm looking for a way to unload collections that haven't been accessed "recently" (some configurable amount of time).

Is there a (good) way to go about doing this?

Comment: Are you able to track table usage in the application code? If so, you can use the `collection.unload()` api call. https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/HTTP/Collection/Modifying.html#unload-collection

Comment: I wish it was that simple. I could implement that solution for processes that may be writing to a collection. For processes reading from it, there could be multiple and they are not coordinated in any way.
The situation where everything is running on a single machine is a kind of special case, but one I need to be able to support, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For version `3.4`, I added the following params to `arangod.conf` to start it in so called `spartan mode`.

More details can be found at their [blog post](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/Manual/Administration/Configuration.html)

```
[javascript]

# number of V8 contexts available for JavaScript execution. use 0 to 
# make arangod determine the number of contexts automatically.
v8-contexts = 1


[foxx]
# enable Foxx queues in the server
# Disable task scheduling - reduce CPU
queues = false


[wal]

# Reduce the number of historic WAL files which will reduce the memory usage when ArangoDB is in use.
historic-logfiles = 1

# Reduce the prepared WAL log files which are kept ready for future write operations
reserve-logfiles = 1

# In addition you can reduce the size of all WAL files to e.g. 8 MB by setting
logfile-size = 8388608
```